# Error trying to fetch data to my dashboard login,codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, fetch

I've made a login system, it works properly.. it opens a different page depending if the username & password written correspond to an admin or a simple user.

Take a look:

[image]

BUT when i wanted to add a table to the "user page" i got this error:

[image]

**The line error:**

[image]

Dont know what to do :/.

Here is my complete code:

**My login view file ("login_form"):**

```
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="container">
            <h3>Login</h3>
            <hr>
            <form action="<?php echo base_url('login/do_login')?>" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cari">USERNAME</label>
                    <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="form-control">

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cari">PASSWORD</label>
                    <input type="password" name="contrasena" id="contrasena" class="form-control">

                </div>

                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login" name="login">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" value="Reset">

            </form>
                </div>



        </body>
</html>
```

**My controller file ("login"):**

```
    <?php

        Class Login extends CI_Controller{


        public function index(){


           $this->load->view('login_form');


        }

 public function do_login()
        {
         // load the form_validation library
         $this->load->library('form_validation');

         $this->form_validation->set_rules('usuario', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|alpha_numeric');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('contrasena', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[6]');

           // if there is errors
         if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) { 
            // this will load your form with the errors

               $this->load->view('login_form'); 

         } else {
           // if no errors we will hit the database
            $user=$this->input->post('usuario', true);
            $pass=$this->input->post('contrasena', true);
            $cek = $this->m_login->proceso_login($user,$pass);
            $hasil=count($cek);

            if($hasil > 0){

                $pelogin =$this->db->get_where('usuarios',array('username' => $user, 'password' => $pass))->row();

                if($pelogin ->type == 0){
                    redirect('login/admin');
                }

                else{
                    redirect('login/usuario');
                }
            }
            redirect('login/index');
        }
    }


            public function home(){

                $data['records']=$this->m_login->getDetails();
                $this->load->view('usuario',$data);
            }
```

**My model file("m_login"):**

```
        public function getDetails()
        {
            $st=$this->db->SELECT('cursadas.*, usuarios.name as usuarios, materias.name as materias_name')->from('cursadas')
                ->join('usuarios','usuarios.id=cursadas.user_id')
                ->join('materias','materias.id=cursadas.subject_id')
                ->WHERE('cursadas.user_id=',$this->session->userdata['id'])
                ->get()->result_array();
            return $st[0]; // or use the row function
        }
```

**AND my dashboard "usuario" (the user page):**

```
                <table class="table table-hover" align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700" id="tabla_busqueda">
                <thead>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                    <th>Grade</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                </thead>


<tbody>
    <?php

    if (count($records) > 0) {
        foreach($records as $record) {

            echo "<tr>
                      <td>".$record['id']."</td>
                      <td>".$record['User']."</td>
                      <td>".$record['name']."</td>
                      <td>".$record['grade']."</td>
                      <td>".$record['date']."</td>
                  </tr>";
        }

       }
    ?>

</tbody>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ask yourself "How and where does `$records` get assigned a value before it is passed to and view? And, have I done all I can to make sure the value assigned is valid?"

Comment: Mate, maybe i am a little dizzy but i do not get it, idonot where the problem is :/

Comment: @DFriend canhelp me to figure it out?:S

Comment: :(, whathappended dude?

Comment: Sorry, had other stuff to do. Make sure that you get good data from model. In other words, is `$st[0]` what you need it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if user is of type admin then it will go to the admin page and if user is normal then it will go to the user page with all its data. You are not sending any user data when user type is not admin. The notice is generated because $records is not available at usuario page when user is not admin
Create admin method for admin and usuario method in your controller which has the corresponding  data

**Your Login Controller :**
 add these methods

```
 // for admin data 
 public function admin (){

  $data['records']=$this->m_login->getDetails();
  $this->load->view('admin_view_page',$data);
}
// for user data 
public function usuario(){

    $data['records']=$this->m_login->getDetails();
    $this->load->view('usuario',$data);
}
```

**modify `do_login` method like this :**

```
if($hasil > 0)
{

   $pelogin =$this->db->get_where('usuarios',array('username' => $user, 'password' => $pass))->row();
  // here $pelogin has the id of the user 
 // create session like this 
  $this->session->set_userdata(array('id' => $pelogin->id));
//  OR  like this 
// $this->session->set_userdata('id', $pelogin->id);

  if($pelogin ->type == 0)
  {
    // here goes  the admin data 
     redirect('admin');
  }

  else{
           //call here usuario method which has user data who logged in like
             redirect('usuario');
          // OR
          // Call some method which has user data in $records and 
      }
}
```

Comment: I swear mate, you helped me a lot.You made realized a lot, thank you very much for that.. But i dont get it, my program does not work properly and i tried but do not know how to modify the query :/

Comment: Take a look:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43301449/error-trying-to-fetch-data-using-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

You have the variable `$records` on view but not on controller

Change

```
$data['record'] = $this->m_login->getDetails();
```

To

```
// add this array() just in case no results found 

$data['records'] = array(); 
$data['records'] = $this->m_login->getDetails();

$this->load->view('usuario', $data);
```

> Another way is on controller

```
public function home() {

$results = $this->m_login->getDetails();

$data['records'] = array(); 

if ($results) {
   foreach ($results as $result) {
      $data['records'][] = array(
         'id' => $result['id'],
         'User' => $result['User'],
         'name' => $result['name'],
         'grade' => $result['grade'],
         'date' => $result['date']
      );
   }
}

$this->load->view('usuario',$data);

}
```

View usuario.php

```
<?php if ($records) {?>
<?php foreach($records as $record) {?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $record['id'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $record['User'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $record['name'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $record['grade'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $record['date'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<tr> 
<td>No Results Found</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

#### just example using php hash

> Tip do not store plan passwords in data base hash password column on db **varchar**
>   **255**

```
<?php

class M_login extends CI_Model {

   public function create_user() {
     $options = [
        'cost' => 12,
     ];

     $new_password = password_hash($this->input->post('password', true), PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

     $data = array(
      'username' => $this->input->post('username', true),
      'password' => $new_password
     );

     $this->db->insert('user', $data);
   }

   public function getpassword($username) {
      $this->db->where('username', $username);
      $query = $this->db->get('user');
      if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->row()->password;
      }
   }

 }
```

Then on login to verify password() use callback

```
<?php 

class Login extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->load->model('m_login');
}

public function index(){
   $this->do_login();
}

public function do_login() {
  $data['somthing'] = 'Hello';


  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'trim|required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required|callback_verify_password');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

       $this->load->view('login_form', $data);

    } else {
       // load success stuff

       /*

          Make sure base url is set in config.php something like

          $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectname/'; 

          End it with /

       */
       redirect(base_url('login/home')); 
    }
}

public function verify_password() {
    // true enables xss_clean
    $stored_hashed = $this->m_login->getpassword($this->input->post('username', true));
    $password = $this->input->post('password', true);

    if (password_verify($password, $stored_hashed)) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
       $this->form_validation->set_message('verify_password', 'Sorry incorrect username or password');
       return FALSE;
    }
}

public function home() {

$results = $this->m_login->getDetails();

$data['records'] = array(); 

if ($results) {
   foreach ($results as $result) {
      $data['records'][] = array(
         'id' => $result['id'],
         'User' => $result['User'],
         'name' => $result['name'],
         'grade' => $result['grade'],
         'date' => $result['date']
      );
   }
}

$this->load->view('usuario',$data);

}


}
```

Comment: But you did not add the admin/usuario functions dude :S. What about that?

Comment: Dude, where should iput this?:
> Another way is on controller

    $results = $this->m_login->getDetails();

    $data['records'] = array(); 

    if ($results) {
       foreach ($results as $result) {
          $data['records'][] = array(
             'id' => $result['id'],
             'User' => $result['User'],
             'name' => $result['name'],
             'grade' => $result['grade'],
             'date' => $result['date']
          );
       }
    }

    $this->load->view('usuario',$data);

Comment: In your home function I have re edited it. also with login example only