# Error trying to fetch data using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, fetch

I got 3 tables; my tables are "cursadas","usuarios" and "materias"

> "cursadas" includes:**(id, user_id[is the foreign key to the column "id" of the table "usuarios"], subject_id[is the foreign key to the column "id" of the table "materias"], grade, date)**
>
> "usuarios" includes:**(id,username,name,lastname,password,type,status,date)**
>
> "materias" includes:**(id, career_id, name, description, hours)**

This is my final table "cursadas"(with data from tables "materias" and "usuarios")

[image]

TAKE A LOOK, i need something like this:

[image]

**I got this error:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

I think there is an error with my query, i do not know what should i do to make this work :S

Here is my code:
My view file ("usuario"):

```
            <input id="busqueda_tabla" type="text">
            <table class="table table-hover" align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700" id="tabla_busqueda">
                <thead>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                    <th>Grade</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                </thead>


<tbody>
    <?php
 
    if (count($records) > 0 && $records != false) {
        foreach($records as $record) {
 
            echo "<tr>
                      <td>".$record['id']."</td>
                      <td>".$record['user']."</td>
                      <td>".$record['name']."</td>
                      <td>".$record['grade']."</td>
                      <td>".$record['date']."</td>
                  </tr>";
        }
 
       }
    ?>
 
</tbody>

</body>
</html>
```

My controller file ("login"):

```
    <?php

        Class Login extends CI_Controller{


        public function index(){
 

           $this->load->view('login_form');


        }

 public function do_login()
        {
         // load the form_validation library
         $this->load->library('form_validation');

         $this->form_validation->set_rules('usuario', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|alpha_numeric');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('contrasena', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[6]');

           // if there is errors
         if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) { 
            // this will load your form with the errors
        
               $this->load->view('login_form'); 

         } else {
           // if no errors we will hit the database
            $user=$this->input->post('usuario', true);
            $pass=$this->input->post('contrasena', true);
            $cek = $this->m_login->proceso_login($user,$pass);
            $hasil=count($cek);

                if($hasil > 0)
                {

                   $pelogin =$this->db->get_where('usuarios',array('username' => $user, 'password' => $pass))->row();
                  // here $pelogin has the id of the user 
                 // create session like this 
                  $this->session->set_userdata(array('id' => $pelogin->id));

                  if($pelogin ->type == 0)
                  {
                    // here goes  the admin data 
                     redirect('login/admin');
                  }

                  else{
                           //call here usuario method which has user data who logged in like
                             redirect('login/usuario');
                          // OR
                          // Call some method which has user data in $records and 
                      }
                }
            redirect('login/index');
        }
    }



            public function admin (){

                  $data['records']=$this->m_login->getDetails();
                  $this->load->view('admin',$data);
                }


            public function usuario(){

                    $data['records']=$this->m_login->getDetails();
                    $this->load->view('usuario',$data);
                }
```

And the model file("m_login")- with the query!

```
    <?php

        class m_login extends CI_Model{

            public function proceso_login($user,$pass){

                $this->db->where('username', $user);
                $this->db->where('password', $pass);
                return $this->db->get('usuarios')->row();

            }



            public function getDetails()
                {
                    $st=$this->db->SELECT('cursadas.*, usuarios.name as usuarios, materias.name as materias_name')->from('cursadas')
                        ->join('usuarios','usuarios.id=cursadas.user_id')
                        ->join('materias','materias.id=cursadas.subject_id')
                        ->WHERE('cursadas.user_id=',$this->session->userdata['id'])
                        ->get()->result_array();
                    return $st[0]; 
                }



}
?>
```

Comment: What is line 37 of usario. Seems like you didn't include it.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 no mate, i got problems with the query! :S

Comment: Inside `foreach($records as $record)` do a `var_dump($record)` to see what keys are there. It is evident from your error messages that `$record['id']` and `$record['user']` are not set.

Comment: @mkaatman I already added it :)

Comment: @Sean you mean this? https://i.gyazo.com/93d95f6503c8fb104ff074f3b4880beb.png

Comment: @Sean https://i.gyazo.com/1f6d2eb6dc225d147c3dd62d6271c34f.png

Comment: It looks like `var_dump($record)` is returning `string(1) "2"`. Since `2` is your `id`, then you are only returning the `id`. Change `return $st[0];` to just `return $st;` inside `public function getDetails()`

Comment: @Sean,i got this error now:
https://i.gyazo.com/6e3b9743430b04b96c54fc9c7b61c752.png

Comment: You currently only have `usuarios.name as usuarios`. So you need to add `usuarios.username as user` -> `'cursadas.*, usuarios.username as user, usuarios.name as usuarios, materias.name as materias_name'`

Comment: You mean this?
https://i.gyazo.com/f52f2f741afdd7b71a77fa53486e5d84.png

Comment: use this : $st = $this->db->SELECT('cursadas.date as date, cursadas.grade as grade, usuarios.name as user, materias.name as subject')->from('cursadas')
                        ->join('usuarios','usuarios.id=cursadas.user_id')
                        ->join('materias','materias.id=cursadas.subject_id')
                        ->WHERE('cursadas.user_id=',$this->session->userdata['id'])
                        ->get()->result_array();
                    return $st;

Comment: No, you have a weird copy in there. It should look like -> `$st=$this->db->SELECT('cursadas.*, usuarios.name as usuarios, usuarios.name as usuarios, materias.name as materias_name')->from('cursadas')`

Comment: You mean this?
https://i.gyazo.com/fe298d5d5ccf0cfca63777ac35849451.png

Comment: yes and print the result

Comment: There is an error, take a look:
https://i.gyazo.com/a81d4b7891e03a08cded0275049fc232.png

Comment: pls tell id is what for is it user id

Comment: @pradeep Why did you change `cursadas.*`? In doing so you now created more issues, like you did not include `cursdas.id`. I will now leave this mess up to you. I am out.

Comment: @Sean, it is not working. It shows this message:
https://i.gyazo.com/add492fe226f16854aeea2734106fddf.png

Comment: My error. I copied `usuarios.name as usuarios` twice, instead of `usuarios.username as user`. it should be `$st=$this->db->SELECT('cursadas.*, usuarios.username as user, usuarios.name as usuarios, materias.name as materias_name')->from('cursadas')`

Comment: yes i know now Pls check this :

Comment: $st = $this->db->SELECT('cursadas.id as id, cursadas.date as date, cursadas.grade as grade, usuarios.name as user, materias.name as subject')->from('cursadas')
                        ->join('usuarios','usuarios.id=cursadas.user_id')
                        ->join('materias','materias.id=cursadas.subject_id')
                        ->WHERE('cursadas.user_id=',$this->session->userdata['id'])
                        ->get()->result_array();
                    return $st;

Comment: @pradeep it has improved mate!, take a look:
https://i.gyazo.com/826ccc22c3e8bdddaefdf84d74afa214.png
https://i.gyazo.com/35c0a73122ba07e21b7f6092c30bc685.png

Comment: @pradeep this is the id used for:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTDrw.png

Comment: @Sean your last code improved too, there is an error:
https://i.gyazo.com/0e608506b2cb52e4b35e395f19eb6538.png

Comment: @Sean, if i change this:
https://i.gyazo.com/90ab9fd9915f1d2e0fb0b57e0570d816.png
using your code i got this:
https://i.gyazo.com/bd776a7b7422056a84f281efef5a1af3.png

Comment: Thank you for helping me @Sean :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the query :

```
$st = $this->db->SELECT('cursadas.date as date, cursadas.grade as grade, usuarios.username as user, materias.name as subject')->from('cursadas')
                    ->join('usuarios','usuarios.id=cursadas.user_id')
                    ->join('materias','materias.id=cursadas.subject_id')
                    ->WHERE('cursadas.user_id=',$this->session->userdata('id'))
                    ->get()->result_array();
                return $st;
```

And pls check the database field type use datetime for date int for id and so as required

**In the view :**

```
<tbody>
<?php

if (count($records) > 0 && $records != false) {
    $id = 1;
    foreach($records as $record) {

        echo "<tr>
                  <td>".$id."</td>
                  <td>".$record['user']."</td>
                  <td>".$record['subject']."</td>
                  <td>".$record['grade']."</td>
                  <td>".$record['date']."</td>
              </tr>";
       $id++;
    }

   }
?>
```

Comment: There is an error:
https://i.gyazo.com/5ccc76e2adbb175bdf934998af0b7581.png

Comment: modify answer pls check again

Comment: Mate, you ARE a genius!, it works now..but can explain what do you do?

Comment: modify query and in the view count the records and repeat them

Comment: Why did you put $id = 1?

Comment: this is for the number of records in the table as u asked for

Comment: Ohh, yeah im a fool.. iget it now pal.Thank you very very much:)

Comment: my pleasure any time

Comment: Mate, can you take a look at this query:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311205/conditional-fetching-data-from-a-table