# Conditional fetching data from a table

Tags: php, codeigniter, fetch

My login system opens a different window if the username &password written correspond to a simple user or an ADMIN.

I got 3 tables:

> "cursadas" includes:**(id, user_id[is the foreign key to the column "id" of the table "usuarios"], subject_id[is the foreign key to the column "id" of the table "materias"], grade, date)**
>
> "usuarios" includes:**(id,username,name,lastname,password,type,status,date)**
>
> "materias" includes:**(id, career_id, name, description, hours)**

This is the table "usuarios":

[image]

So,when i write a simple user (type & status = 1) a page only for simple users appears:

**So,this is my new goal to my program:**

[image]

**Do not know how to do the query :S**

***Here is my user dashboard ("info_user"):***

```
                <table class="table table-hover" align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700" id="tabla_busqueda">
                <thead>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                </thead>


<tbody>
<?php

if (count($records) > 0 && $records != false) {
    $id = 1;
    foreach($records as $record) {

        echo "<tr>
                  <td>".$id."</td>
                  <td>".$record['username']."</td>
                  <td>".$record['name']."</td>
                  <td>".$record['lastname']."</td>
                  <td>".$record['date']."</td>
              </tr>";
       $id++;
    }

   }
?>
 
</tbody>

</body>
</html>
```

***My controller function:***

```
        public function info_user(){

            $data['records']=$this->m_login->getINFO();
            $this->load->view('info_user',$data);
        }
```

***And the model function "getInfo" (do not know how to do the query):***

```
            public function getINFO()
            {
               $st = $this->db->SELECT()
                ->join()
                ->join()
                ->WHERE()
                ->get()->result_array();
            return $st; 
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Your model add this method:**

```
    public function getINFO(){

    $query = $this->db->get_where('usuarios', array('id' => $this->session->userdata('id')));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

See this link for more :

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-arrays

Comment: Hey dude, i got this error:
https://i.gyazo.com/5883709564d705d4858441551522019e.png
https://i.gyazo.com/d84275b64eb3aa69910917f7f8a24b7c.png

Comment: Dude, i got this error now:
https://i.gyazo.com/1022f1f6fc0903ce546537583271c84f.png
https://i.gyazo.com/8cbceba59f34443b27977bbe64f3ea25.png

and so on :S

Comment: print the result in the controller in the info_user method]

Comment: You mean var_dump?

Comment: print_r($data);

Comment: EDIT: mate, if you wonder i've changed the name and lastname of my table :)

Comment: since it has only one record so remove the foreach loop

Comment: user this :  if ($records)  {
   
   

        echo "<tr>
                  <td>".$records['id']."</td>
                  <td>".$records['username']."</td>
                  <td>".$records['name']."</td>
                  <td>".$records['lastname']."</td>
                  <td>".$records['date']."</td>
              </tr>";
      
    }

Comment: use this and see the results]

Comment: Thank you pal,you are awesome :D.
My program works properly, but there is something wrong.. when i logout the session ends BUT is press this:
https://i.gyazo.com/a7c12f3534025c879d91920b82445df8.png

I got this error:
https://i.gyazo.com/be8dad0660dc7a0141571ecddfbe6910.png

Here the code:
https://i.gyazo.com/a80065e3fc88e9347bed20bcb9ed88f8.png

Comment: u have to destroy the session in the logout method and then redirect to the login page

Comment: I mean,if i press this https://i.gyazo.com/a7c12f3534025c879d91920b82445df8.png without clicking the button "logout" everything works fine.. If i logout it redirects me to the login page AND if i press the button to go back in that page, it shows that error

Comment: Yeah, this is my function:
https://i.gyazo.com/a337dcbe96cbba9fc6fb8c08ecf6a977.png

Comment: in that case u have to code in your method if session id is found then redirect to the user page otherwise redirect to the login page

Comment: Dude, take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312420/error-after-loggin-out

Comment: Mate, take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312816/encrypt-password-login-system-codeigniter
It is about encryption

Comment: Dude, what would be the query if I WANT TO SHOW ALL "simple" users from table "usuarios" (not ADMIN users).
With this query the program shows only the users that log in:
https://i.gyazo.com/4ca01f5dc78377cda2a01dff422a95e0.png

BUT NOW,i wanna show all "simple" users stored in table "usuarios".
Whatwould be the query pal? :S

Comment: use this method :  public function get_all_users(){
   //here $admin_id will the id of the admin
    $query = $this->db->get_where('usuarios', array('id !=' =>  $admin_id));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
      return $query->row_array();
    }
 
  }