# Error after loggin out

Tags: php, codeigniter, fetch

My program works properly.. it has several pages and if i click on the button of the browser to go back, it goes to the previous page:

BUT there is an error after loggin out.
When i logged out the program redirects me to the login page, everything seems to be working fine but it does not

When i click on "logout" and the program redirects me to the login system IF I press the button in the browser to go back i got this error:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgNLK.png]

Do not know what is going on :/

Here is the program line error:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M0ZS.png]

My code, the model file ("m_login"):

```
public function getDetails()
{
   $st = $this->db->SELECT('cursadas.date as date, cursadas.grade as grade, usuarios.username as user, materias.name as subject')->from('cursadas')
    ->join('usuarios','usuarios.id=cursadas.user_id')
    ->join('materias','materias.id=cursadas.subject_id')
    ->WHERE('cursadas.user_id=',$this->session->userdata['id'])
    ->get()->result_array();
return $st; 
}
```

My logout function:

```
        public function logout(){

        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('login/index');

    }
```

Comment: show your index method and do_login method

Comment: change   $this->session->userdata['id']  by this code $this->session->userdata('id')

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Looks like you need to learn more about what is expected of users here. You are expected to [do your research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). This question is too broad: it suggests: 1) you have not researched what the error means, 2) you have not played around with the most minimal code to reproduce and learn, etc. Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change getDetails() method by this**

```
// $this->session->userdata['id'] to this code $this->session->userdata('id')


public function getDetails()
{
 $st = $this->db->SELECT('cursadas.date as date, cursadas.grade as grade,
usuarios.username as user, materias.name as subject')->from('cursadas')
->join('usuarios','usuarios.id=cursadas.user_id')
->join('materias','materias.id=cursadas.subject_id')
->WHERE('cursadas.user_id=',$this->session->userdata('id'))
->get()->result_array();
return $st; 
}
```

see the link for more info

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data

Comment: Mate, can you take a look at this:
https://i.gyazo.com/94e7386636da1c5429c0b18e8ae4826b.png

Comment: @idontknow what is it?

Comment: i gotta make a query with the data shown in the image.